# Elasticsearch - no results with nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

What I am doing wrong? I dont get any result from my nested properties:

```
GET my_app_name/my_model/_search
{"query": {"match_all": {} } }

# results
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_app_name",
    "_type": "my_model",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "categories": [
        {
          "name": "SomeCategoryName"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 ]
```

my mapping:

```
{
  "my_app_name": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_model": {
        "properties": {
          "categories": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Query

```
# GET my_app_name/my_model/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "categories.name": "SomeCategoryName"
        }}
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

also tried this

```
# GET my_app_name/my_model/_search
{
  "query": {"match": {
    "categories.name": "SomeCategoryName"
  }}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested objects are treated as separate docs, hence `nested` is needed in the query.

```
GET my_app_name/my_model/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "categories",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "categories.name": "SomeCategoryName"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Refer: [nested-query-dsl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#query-dsl-nested-query)

Comment: Thank you it worked! Can you explain me please what's the difference w/o "nested"? Only for completion: When I keep out the nested part of the index, I was able to query with this: ```{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"categories.alias": "SomeCategoryName"} } ] }}```
}

Comment: to answer my question: * Nested docs are stored in the same Lucene block as each other, which helps read/query performance. * Reading a nested doc is faster than the equivalent parent/child. *
Updating a single field in a nested document (parent or nested children) forces ES to reindex the entire nested document. This can be very expensive for large nested docs
* “Cross referencing” nested documents is impossible
* Best suited for data that does not change frequently

Comment: Thanks @Jan for the info provided on reindexing.  Here's a reference in terms of flattening of array objects: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_how_arrays_of_objects_are_flattened